# I wish to return the number of limit based on the field/column in SQL

Tags: sql

I try to use the limit in SQL to perform limit on rows but somehow I wish to have the limit based on the field instead. like we can have many rows but the limit on table 1 should be 500.

Code:

```
select
 table1,
 table2
from
 place_table
limit 100 --I wish to change this. to only focus on table1 for 100 data.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Table s have _columns_, not fields. And table1 and table2 are really bad column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by <col>) as seqnum
      from place_table p
     ) p
where seqnum <= <limit col>
```

`<col>` is a column to specify the ordering -- which  rows you want.

Comment: hi thank you but is it not possible to exclude the order by because I dont need to order it

Comment: this is not working sir because in my data, the table1 contain duplicate due to table2. its like table1:king, table:man, then table1:king, table2:woman and so on. so when I use your method and if the table1 has 100 duplicates then it will only take the 100 similar duplicates

Comment: @Anony . . . This answers your question.  None of that information is in the question.  You have simply asked for a method for using a column to determine the number of rows in the result set, which this doesn.